# rails3 map application,what's the scope about latitude & longitude

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, latitude-longitude, geography

currently i work a geo-relevent app use google map,
but i don't have much knowledge about Geography,so i want to ask what't latitude & longitude
scope min to max

e.g 
lat 37.314
long 40.7302

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578799.aspx

Answer (score 2):

min/max values are:

Latitude: -90 to 90
Equator is 0. South Pole is -90 and North Pole is 90

Longitude: -180 to 180
Prime Meridian (Greenwich, England) is 0
International Dateline is 180